# How to use @InjectMocks and initMocks() with an object that has a required String parameter?

Tags: mocking, mockito

Given a component to test that requires a non-mockable class (`String`) in it's constructor injection, like this:

```java
public class MyService {
    @Inject
    public MyService(String param1, SomeObject param2) {
            ...
    }
}
```

I want to use Mockito to test it with a test harness like this:

```java
public class MyServiceTests {
    @Mock
    private SomeObject someObject;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }
}
```

Problem is, I can't `@Spy` or `@Mock` Strings (because `String` is a final class). So how can I use Mockito and "inject" a specific String value for the `param1` argument to `MyService`'s constructor (or otherwise test this class that requires a non-null String be passed)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the simple answer is not to use `@InjectMocks`, and instead to initialise your object directly. The only downside I can see is that you're not testing the injection, but then with `@InjectMocks`, I think you'd be testing it with Mockito's injection implementation, rather than your real framework's implementation anyway, so no real difference.

I'd do:

```java
public class MyServiceTests {
  @Mock
  private SomeObject someObject;

  private MyService service;

  @Before
  public void setUp() {
    service = new MyService("foo", someObject);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
@InjectMocks
private MyService service= new  MyService( param1 , param2 );
```

Comment: This answer would be better if you explain how this achieves what the OP is asking for, as I think (but am not sure) that the `@InjectMocks` annotation is redundant here.

Comment: If the @InjectMocks is removed, a NPE is thrown